# After the successful token generation I get 401 error when I try to get my mails via Graph API

Tags: azure, powershell, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to write a Powershell script to get my emails from my outlook via Oauth2 token without user login, but unfortunately no luck. I am able to generate correctly my token successfully and I can see on "jwt.ms" website there is a required permission on it, but for some reason its just not working.

If I generate a token with "graph explorer" and paste into my code directly, (so if I am not generating the token from Powershell code), all option works fine and I can get back all details from my outlook. So its something regarding the token and permission but I am not sure what exactly.

[image]

Interesting thing is, if I change thte code from:

```
$Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/*********************************/messages"
```

to:

```
$Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/*********************************/
```

In this case the API will give back my profile details.

jwt.ms result:
https://pastebin.com/tMmxfn5d

```
 "roles": [
    "Mail.ReadWrite",
    "Mail.ReadBasic.All",
    "Directory.Read.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "Mail.Read",
    "Mail.Send",
    "Contacts.Read",
    "Mail.ReadBasic"
  ],
```

Error message:

```
Invoke-RestMethod: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. At line:29 char:17
+ ... rResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

My powershell code:

```
# Define the URI and parameters
$Uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/*********************************/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$Body = @{
    "grant_type"    = "client_credentials"
    "client_id"     = "*********************************"
    "client_secret" = "*********************************"
    "scope"      = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
}
$ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

# Send the POST request
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $Uri -Body $Body -ContentType $ContentType


# Display the access token
Write-Output "Access Token: $($Response.access_token)"

# Replace "{id | userPrincipalName}" with the id or userPrincipalName of the user
$Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/*********************************/messages"

# Define the header for the "user" request
$Headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $($Response.access_token)"
}


# Send the GET request
$UserResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers

# Display the "user" information
Write-Output $UserResponse
```

Comment: You need to add the token to the request : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3#example-5-pass-multiple-headers

Comment: token request has been added in the begining of code:

"# Define the URI and parameters
$Uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/*********************************/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$Body = @{
    "grant_type"    = "client_credentials"
    "client_id"     = "*********************************"
    "client_secret" = "*********************************"
    "scope"      = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
}
$ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

# Send the POST request
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $Uri -Body $Body -ContentType $ContentType"

Comment: I don't see something wrong with your code. Seems totally fine. API permissions are also more than enough

Comment: Yes, this is how i see also... I tried many way, but always the same issue.

Comment: I think the problem lies here: "There are two scenarios where an app can get messages in another user's mail folder: - If the app has application permissions, or, - If the app has the appropriate delegated permissions from one user, and another user has shared a mail folder with that user, or, has given delegated access to that user." So, essentially, seems like you need to delegate mailbox permission to the app (if i understood correctly). See the API doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: When you do authentication you perform two request 1) Get Token 2) Perform query with token added to the request.  The second request needs the token.

Comment: All 3 permission has been added to this App:
Mail.ReadBasic, Mail.Read, Mail.ReadWrite, so shouldnt be a problem with the permission.

The second request including the token:

"$Headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $($Response.access_token)"
}"

Comment: zsolti: what I understand from reading the API doc is, the delegated app permission allow the app to query the API, however that doesn't mean the APP has permissions over all mailboxes in the Tenant. The App needs to have delegated permissions over the mailbox too. Im just guessing here, not an Exchange guy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved.

This Graph API only works only with work email (personal free email not suitable for this method). So I subsribed for a microsoft exchange account for 4GBP and everything work perfectly.